# "Do you have a lock for my key?"

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember, back when I was in middle school, reading a story that opened with a meeting of two shadowy figures.  One asked the other, "do you have a lock for my key?"  And the other brought out some magic item that they had been looking for, that they had the means to utilize.

It's been a long time, and I don't remember much in the way of details, but that line has always stuck with me.  I know this isn't much to go on, but can anyone help identify this book?

Comment: Anyone else flashing on the Sigourney Weaver & Rick Moranis in Ghostbusters?  "Are you the Keymaster?", 'Are you the Gatekeeper?"

Comment: That sentence rings a bell, but the only *Fantasy* I've read is Terry Pratchett's DiscWorld. Could it be one of these?

Comment: @Thecafremo: No, I never read any of his stuff until recently.

Comment: This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Answer (score 4):

It's from the beginning of the point&click adventure game [*Indiana Jones and the Fate of Atlantis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indiana_Jones_and_the_Fate_of_Atlantis) by LucasArts.

> *"Tell me, did you find a lock to match my key?"*

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Nice find, if this is correct.  You can improve this answer by quoting the scene from the game (screenshots are great) or by finding sources online.

Comment: @DavidW It's worth noting that the OP is specifically looking for a book and this is not one if I am correct.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot This is true, but we do permit partial answers, and maybe this game had a tie-in novel, or maybe the OP was just confused about where they read it...